# How to add data to specific index of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which contains usernames, which I have created by using array_push to add each item in a foreach loop to the array:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "Username1"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "Username2"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "Username3"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "Username4"
}
```

I also have an ID number stored in `$id`

How can I change the array so that it stores both the `username` and `ID` nested together in the array? Or if not that way, what's the best way to keep these two items of data associated in the array?

This is the code to create the array `$accounts_list` which currently only stores the username.

```
$all_accounts = [];
   foreach ($accounts_list as &$account) {
      $name = $account['name'];
      array_push($all_accounts,$name);

      $id = $account['id'];
   }
```

Comment: make an array like this :
$array[id]=username
I think it is the best way

Comment: Why aren't you using `$accounts_list` simply as is?! It appears to be an array or arrays, which contain `name` and `id` keys; exactly what you want it seems.

Comment: And why are using foreach with reference ?

Comment: looking at the loop, they are already in the same place: `$account['name'], $account['id']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create an array with elements of associative array.

```
$users = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'username' => 'John'),
    array('id' => 2, 'username' => 'Smith'),
    array('id' => 3, 'username' => 'Monica'),
    //...
);
```

But i think, that is much more better, if you are using classes for your users.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$all_accounts = array();
foreach ($accounts_list as $account) {
   $all_accounts[$account['id']] = $account['name']'
}
```

then access array like:  `$all_accounts['account_id']`